# How to add a space after a \string command otput in .log file

Tags: revtex, strings

Consider this code, adapted from the command `\incompatible@package` of `RevTex4-2`.
The relevant part is just the `\string\usepackage\ statement` in the line beginning with `\def\@tempa`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\makeatletter

\def\class@name{SomeClass}
\def\incompatible@package#1{%
 \@ifpackageloaded{#1}{%
  \def\@tempa{I cannot continue. You must remove the \string\usepackage\ statement that caused that package to be loaded.}%
  \ClassError{\class@name}{The #1 package cannot be used with \class@name}%
  \@tempa\stop
 }{%
%   \class@info{#1 was not loaded (OK!)}% This is uncommented in the original, but I don't need it
 }%
}%

\incompatible@package{cite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

In the .log file, there will be a message that reads (pay attention to the *\usepackage* part),

> I cannot continue. You must remove the \usepackage\ statement that
> caused that package to be loaded.

Presumably, we want the output to read *\usepackage statement*, not *\usepackage\ statement*.

The following fixes don't work:

`\string\usepackage statement` gives *\usepackagestatement*
`\string\usepackage~statement` gives *\usepackage\nobreakspace {}statement*
`{\string\usepackage} statement` gives *{\usepackage} statement*
`\string\usepackage {}statement` gives *\usepackage{}statement*

I did find one way to fix it:

`\expandafter\string\csname usepackage \endcsname` gives *\usepackage statement*

But that seems heavy-handed.

Is there a simpler, better way to get the desired result (using just core LaTeX)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\noexpand` instead of `\string`.

```
I cannot continue. You must remove the \usepackage statement that caused that p
ackage to be loaded.
```

Also `\string\usepackage\space` would do, but `\noexpand` is shorter.

I don't see why defining `\@tempa`:

```
\def\class@name{SomeClass}
\def\incompatible@package#1{%
 \@ifpackageloaded{#1}{%
  \ClassError{\class@name}{%
    The #1 package cannot be used with \class@name
  }{I cannot continue. You must remove the \noexpand\usepackage statement
    that caused that package to be loaded.%
  }%
  \stop
 }{%
%   \class@info{#1 was not loaded (OK!)}% This is uncommented in the original,
%               but I don't need it
 }%
}%
```

Comment: One could argue that `\string\usepackage\space`, while not the shortest solution, is the solution that's most 'in the spirit of the question', in the sense that it's closest to the coder's original idea. But that's of course a matter of taste!
No idea why the coder chose to go through `\@tempa`, either.